# Angular Directive calling $http

Tags: angularjs

I am having trouble when using multiple instances of the following directive. Randomly, I will get the wrong list back in my success method. scope.type is always 'correct'; meaning it is what I passed in. The response will sometimes be the response from a different call.

The directive:

```
angular.module('dincApp.directives').directive('lwSelect',
   ['$log', 'optionsService', '$http',
   function ($log, optionsService, $http) {

   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,

      scope:{
         placeholder : '@',
         type : '@'
      },

      link: function (scope, element, attr) {
         $log.info('scope.type = ' + scope.type);

         scope.options = {};

         $http({method: 'GET', url: '/options/' + scope.type}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
               $log.info('scope.type = ' + scope.type);
               $log.info('data = ' + JSON.stringify(data));
               scope.options = data;
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
               $log.debug('Error retrieving select options');
            });
      },

      template:
         '<select ng-options="option.key as option.value for option in options" ' +
         '>' +
         '<option value="">-- {{placeholder}} {{type}} --</option>' +
         '</select>'

   };
}]);
```

The html:

```
<lw-select id="stateSelect"
           placeholder="State"
           class="form-control"
           name="state"
           ng-model="profile.state"
           type="State"
           >
</lw-select>
```

Any ideas? I tried using a $resource as well, but the same issue occurs. I'm not sure it's related to the directive. I experienced similar behavior when I made several calls to the same $resource in a controller too.

UPDATE:

I have moved this logic out of the directive into the controller and experience the same issue. These calls in the controller will work some of the time. Others I will get the list of states returned for the countries and vice versa. It's like there is a race condition. Are these calls not separate instances?

Controller:

```
       optionsService.retrieve({optionType:"State"}).$promise.then(
           function success(response) {
              $log.debug('Options response for stateOptions:' + JSON.stringify(response));
              $scope.stateOptions = response;
           },
           function failure() {
              $log.error('Error retrieving select options');
           });

        optionsService.retrieve({optionType:"Country"}).$promise.then(
           function success(response) {
              $log.debug('Options response for countryOptions:' + JSON.stringify(response));
              $scope.countryOptions = response;
           },
           function failure() {
              $log.error('Error retrieving select options');
           });
        ....
```

Resource:

```
angular.module('dincApp.services').factory('optionsService',
['$resource',
  function ($resource) {
     return $resource('/options/:optionType', {}, {
        retrieve: { method: 'GET', isArray: true }
     });
  }]);
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell exactly what you mean but try setting a variable to your $http return (ie the promise) and in the 'then' set the data.  var val = $http(....); val.then(function(data) { $scope.options = data;});  That sort of thing

Comment: Basically, I have several instances of the directive on the same page. I thought I was using isolation scope. scope.type looks correct in my logs. They randomly have each others return data.

Comment: rather than doing this in link do it in controller

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing this in `link` do it in `controller`:

```
angular.module('dincApp.directives')

.directive('lwSelect', ['$log', 'optionsService', '$http',
    function ($log, optionsService, $http) {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,

            scope: {
                placeholder: '@',
                type: '@'
            },

            controller: ['$scope', function (scope) {
                $log.info('scope.type = ' + scope.type);

                scope.options = {};

                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '/options/' + scope.type
                }).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $log.info('scope.type = ' + scope.type);
                    $log.info('data = ' + JSON.stringify(data));
                    scope.options = data;
                }).
                error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $log.debug('Error retrieving select options');
                });
           }],

            template: '<select ng-options="option.key as option.value for option in options" ' +
                '>' +
                '<option value="">-- {{placeholder}} {{type}} --</option>' +
                '</select>'
        };
    }]);
```